# Printing staircase revisited

Tags: javascript, node.js, ascii-art

What can be more elegant ways to solve the given problem.

```
    #
   ##
  ###
 ####
```

**Code:**

```
function StairCase(n) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        var col = i;
        for(var j = 1; j <= n - col; j++) {
            process.stdout.write(' ');
        }
        for(var j = 1; j <= col; j++) {
            process.stdout.write('#');
        }
        process.stdout.write('\n');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JavaScript function names should start with a lowercase character, and "staircase" is one compound word in English.

Since every line is nearly the same, and only one character changes at a time, you should take advantage of that and use an array as a buffer.

```
function staircase(n) {
    var line = Array(n + 1).fill(' ');
    line[n] = '\n';
    for (var i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        line[i] = '#';
        process.stdout.write(line.join(''));
    }
}
```

Comment: [Similar answer in Java](/a/140336/9357)

Answer (score 6):

No need for the additional for loops:

```
function StairCase(n) {
    var s = '';
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            s += ' '.repeat(n - i) + '#'.repeat(i)  + '\n';
    }
    return s;
}
```

If you don't have [repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) for some reason, another implementation could be:

```
String.prototype.Repeat = function(count) {
    var ret = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){
        ret += this.valueOf();
    }
    return ret;
}

function StairCase(n) {
    var s = '';
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            s += ' '.Repeat(n - i) + '#'.Repeat(i)  + '\n';
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Why not write `Repeat` as `String.prototype.repeat`? Wouldn't that allow for more flexibility?

Comment: @HemanGandhi Thanks, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Why not write `String.prototype.repeat` as `repeat`, to avoid polluting the global namespace?

Answer (score 6):

This traditional Javascript code works fine:

```
function staircase(n) {
  var line = Array(n + 1).fill(' ');
  //line[n] = '';
  for (var i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    line[i] = '#';
    console.log(line.join(''));
  }
}
```

and ES6 we can write:

```
const staircase = n => {
  const line = Array(n + 1).fill(' ');
  //line[n] = ''; 
  for (let i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    line[i] = '#';
    console.log(line.join(''));
  }
}
```

If our given input is 6 the output should be:

```
     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
```

Answer (score 4):

No need to use two `for` loops, you can use `repeat` function inside for loop.

See the below example.

```
var staircase = "",
    n = 6,
    space = " ",
    hash = "#";
for(var i = n ; i > 0 ;i--){
    staircase+=space.repeat(i-1).concat(hash.repeat(n-(i-1))) + "\n";
}
console.log(staircase);
```

Output Will be :

```
     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
```

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange Code Review! Please see: [How do I write a good answer?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), where you will find: "Every answer must make at least one insightful observation about the code in the question. Answers that merely provide an alternate solution with no explanation or justification do not constitute valid Code Review answers and may be deleted".

Answer (score 0):

The last loop must not be the same as the previous one, because the problem ask for not leave any space characters. So You need to skip from creating it as '\n'.

```
let i = 0;
let stair = '';

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    if (i < n) {
    stair += ' '.repeat(n - i) + '#'.repeat(i) + '\n';   
    } else {
        stair += '#'.repeat(i);   


    } 
}

console.log(stair)

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Your answer states: "_the problem ask for not leave any space characters_". Where is this mentioned?

Comment: (if you terminated the loop on `i < n`, you would not need a conditional statement unless to provide for n < 1.)

Comment: Please format your code properly. While here, you must also fix the trailing `}` at the end, which has no `{` counterpart.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer use functional and prototypical inheritance over native loops because it's cleaner. And I use MAP because ES6 feature is far more short and useful, though MAP has no side effects.

```js
const reversedArr = (n) => Array.from(Array(n).keys()).reverse()

const staircase = (n) => reversedArr(n).map((value, index) => {
        return console.log(' '.repeat(value)+'#'.repeat(index+1)+'\n')
    })

staircase(50)
```

func is a output of a logic: `Array.from(Array(n).keys()).reverse()` that receives `n:integer` parameter.

Array.from is a new syntax from ES6, it means that you can fill an array from "here" to "there" ie: `Array.from(0, 6)` returns `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]`

so all the `staircase(n)` return is a output of map of this array. Such array that receive `Array(n).keys()` and reverses it with prototype `reverse()`

so that the array could be: `[6,5,4,3,2,1,0]` instead.

the map repeat iterate over the array created from `Array.from(Array(n).keys()).reverse()`
and return a log for each item such as every item repeats `' '` (blank space) + "#" at the end of this string.

Comment: Can you add an intuition or a rationale for your preference?

Comment: It's clear? back here with what you did not get.

Comment: My question has been and is *Why prefer this over the code as presented in the question?*, not *Does this indeed work, and why?* (Intuition would be something like *I think I prefer this because I generally prefer functional style coding*, rationale something like *This has 13 tokens instead of 42, so it is easier to understand and maintain*)

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank you

Comment: @greybeard you know how can I test the efficiency of my data structure over the other?

Comment: `arr` is a terrible name for a function that returns a reversed range.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution using ES6 `array.map()` with no for-loop used, which to me is the most clear and intuitive solution:

```
function staircase(n) {
    // intiate an empty n*n matrix
    let matrix = Array(n).fill().map(() => Array(n).fill());

    matrix.map((curArr, idY) => { // for each array row in matrix
        curArr.map((curVal, idX) => { // for each element in the current array row
            // evaluate each element's to-be-assigned value
            matrix[idY][idX] = (idX + idY + 1 >= n) ? '#' : ' ';
        }, [])
    }, [])

    // convert each row into string
    matrix.forEach((row) => {
        console.log(row.join(''));
    })
    // now we have the staircase
}
```

If you're interested, go researching about functional programming, pure functions and immutability.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Your current answer is an alternative implementation, not really a review of the code provided. While alternative implementations can be a good part of an answer, all answers should at least say something about the code and/or approach provided in the question.

Comment: Can you please argue an increase in *elegance* of the proposed use of nested `map()`s over the code presented in the question?

Answer (score -1):

No need to declare loads of variables.

```
function staircase(n) {
    let a = "#";
    for(let i =1;i<=n;i++){
        console.log(" ".repeat(n-i)+a.repeat(i))
    }
}
```